# Re-Direct users to newly created opportunity in process builder

Tags: visualforce, process-builder, opportunity, automation, redirect

I have created a process builder which clones the opportunity when its 'closed won' from [here](https://automationchampion.com/2015/02/16/getting-started-with-process-builder-part-3-clone-a-record/)

The opportunity creates fine but I want the user to **either be redirected to that opportunity** straight away or to **show a message to give the option to proceed to the cloned page** (optional)

Can this be done using a visualforce page? How do I call it from the flow?

Answer (score 1):

Through process builder its not possible as it doesn't have UI context. 
To accomplish this requirement there are two ways which I can think of as below :

1. Create a Visual Force page (with standard controller) and at **apex:page** tag there is an attribute called **Action** which will call controller method. Write all your logic for cloning record and redirection in that method. Create a Custom button (Detail page button) on opportunity object and call that VF page.
2. We can also call the visual flow form this newly created custom button. Please refer [this](https://andyinthecloud.com/2014/02/19/clicks-not-code-with-visual-flow-custom-buttons/) link for more info. Here [Andrew Fawcett](https://twitter.com/andyinthecloud) has explained how to use the finishLocation attribute to define a URL that the Flow would navigate to after it completed.

Drawback for above approaches is that we need to manual click the custom button when the opportunity is closed won.